# unable to open include file `test.inc` in sasm

Tags: nasm, sasm

I am using SASM on Ubuntu to try out some NASM assembler coding. To test my assembler code I have created a test file and saved it in the same directory as my .asm File, but when I try to debug it in SASM I am getting the following error:

> unable to open include file `test.inc`

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this issue by going to Options -> Build and then selecting the “Build in current directory” option in the SASM Program

[image]